# Adding Access Policy for Managed Service Identity

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell

As part of Powershell script I am provisioning FunctionApp and KeyVault. Script also enables the MSI on function app. I need to add access policy on keyvault for the functionApp. How can I add this access policy? I could not find an example to do this on MSDN.

```
New-AzResource -ResourceType 'Microsoft.Web/Sites' -ResourceName $FuncAppName -Kind 'functionapp' -Location $defaultRegion -ResourceGroupName $defaultRG -Properties @{ }  -Force
set-AzWebApp -ResourceGroupName $defaultRG -AssignIdentity $true -Name $FuncAppName -HttpsOnly $true | Out-Null

$KeyVault = New-AzKeyVault -Name $KeyVaultName -ResourceGroupName $defaultRG -Location $defaultRegion
Set-AzKeyVaultAccessPolicy -VaultName $KeyVault.VaultName -UserPrincipalName $settingsServiceAccountName -PermissionsToSecrets set, get -PassThru | Out-Null
```

I am able to add a user principle but am not aware how to add a function app.

Comment: So did you get an error? And actually what is your question? The `Set-AzKeyVaultAccessPolicy` is the right way.

Comment: I am able to add a user principle but don't know how to add an app for access policy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `-ObjectId` parameter, it is the object id of your MSI.

```
Set-AzKeyVaultAccessPolicy -VaultName 'Contoso03Vault' -ObjectId 34595082-9346-41b6-8d6b-295a2808b8db -PermissionsToSecrets Get,Set
```

To get the object id of the MSI, use the command as below. Make sure you have 
 already enabled the MSI.

```
$objectid = (Get-AzWebApp -ResourceGroupName <ResourceGroupName> -Name <functionname>).Identity.PrincipalId
```

Comment: thanks, How do I get the objectId in the above context, I am creating the function app first